# tsc doesn't detect Angular2 RC definitions

Tags: typescript, angular, tsc

I am using angular **2.0.0-rc.1**, but am struggling with the typescript compiler (Typescript **1.8.10**). If I run tsc on my project, I get loads of errors like this:

> app/app.component.ts(1,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'

However, I thought that because the `package.json` in node_modules/@angular/core has the line:

```
  "typings": "index.d.ts",
```

and `index.d.ts` provides the definitions, this shouldn't be the case? VSCode doesn't highlight any issues with these packages and will link through to the source if I click "Go to Definition" on the imports.

What should I do to avoid compiler errors like this?

## Update:

My `packages.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "platforms"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why no upgrade to Angular 2 RC.3

Comment: @AngJobs I am working on the nativescript runtime, which is better documented for RC1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json` exclude `node_modules` folder

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {

        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,

        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "watch":true
      },
      "compileOnSave": true,
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts",

        "typings"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Please see my updated question, I have excluded node_modules, although am missing some of the other options in your answer, are those important?

Comment: Yes, I think you should exclude those too.